# ListView Row Height Too Small

Tags: android, android-layout

Below is an image of a `ListView` row that is too short. I've tried too many combinations and yield my frustration to StackOverflow.

[image]

How can I fix this and show the whole row? Here is the XML for the item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/item_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/item_left"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status_day"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/item_left_text"
            android:textSize="25sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/item_right"
        android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/item_right_text"
                android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/item_right_text"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/options"
        android:background="@drawable/item_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: post you code portion where you inflate the `listview` with data and the parent layout xml file where the `listview` is placed

Comment: wrap_content height for root and childs surely works if you can use it.

Comment: I had same problem but I fixed after I saw Khan's answer. first the outer layout should have match_parent or fill_parent and then set height of child view's height to some fixed height like 40dp. it worked!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I set the height of the `ImageButton` to `match_parent`.

This fixed the issue oddly. Sigh.

Answer (score 5):

can you use this, set row layout height

```
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
```

Answer (score 3):

your layout should be in such manner for your requirement i have pasted not same as your's layout but related to it check it

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >
     <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp" >

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/ivArrow"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
           android:focusable="false"
           android:clickable="false"
           android:src="@drawable/arrow" />
       <RelativeLayout
           android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="60dp"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:focusable="false"
           android:clickable="false"
           android:background="@drawable/oddnumbg" >



           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/tvNo"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
               android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
               android:textColor="@color/ReceiptNoLable"
               android:text="No." />

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/tvReceiptNo"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_centerInParent="true"
               android:singleLine="true"
               android:layout_below="@+id/tvNo"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:textColor="@color/ReceiptSavedColor"
               android:textSize="18dp"
               android:text="1234" />
           </RelativeLayout>

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tvSubName"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
           android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivIcon"
           android:text="RECEIVED FROM"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:focusable="false"
           android:clickable="false"
           android:textColor="@color/ReceiptNoLable"
            />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tvName"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivIcon"
           android:layout_below="@+id/tvSubName"
           android:text="RECEIPT"
           android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
           android:textColor="@color/ReceiptSavedColor"
           android:textSize="30dp"
           android:focusable="false"
           android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvReceiptPrize"
           android:clickable="false"
           android:singleLine="true"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tvReceiptPrize"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivArrow"
           android:background="@drawable/myreceiptprizebg"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:singleLine="true"
           android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
           android:textSize="20dp"
           android:textColor="#fff"
           android:text="$84.20" />

        </RelativeLayout>


  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

just set the height of the outer layout, instead of using `fill_parent`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:awesome="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height=50dp <!-- or anything which fits -->
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Setting the height doesn't change anything. I tried both 50dp and 100dp just to check and neither budges the height.

Comment: have you made sure you haven't hard coded the height of the list view (or its parent, or their parent.. and so on) ? and its 'wrap_content' ?

Comment: No height calculations. I doubled checked, and no parents of the list view have calculated heights. If I put in a larger ImageButton, it causes the row to enlarge. Almost as if the height of the row is determined by that last view.

Comment: that sure is strange. Experiment with your Gravity and Layout_gravity tags, I've witnessed unusual layout behavior when gravity comes into play.